# Does Google Desktop Search have a separate 64-bit Windows version?

Tags: 64-bit, google-desktop-search

I ask because [it's being discontinued](http://googledesktop.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-desktop-update.html) very soon and I'd like to make sure I've downloaded all versions. (I only have 32-bit Windows installed at the moment and the [website](http://desktop.google.com/) might serve a different binary depending on your operating system)

Comment: Have you considered alternatives: Copernic Desktop Search, Exalead Desktop Search, InSight Desktop Search

Answer (score 3):

No, they did not create a 64 bit version.  Later [versions](http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=25631) were compatible with 64 bit systems.  There was no need or benefit in creating a 64 bit version, as its internal database was small and quick.

Do you really want a desktop search application gobbling up 4GB or more of memory if it was available to it?

Comment: A 64-bit executable doesn't necessarily use a lot more memory. The main thing is that it's more future-proof, eg. if Microsoft drops support for 32-bit.

Comment: Actually, it does eat up more memory.  Those 32bit data structures? Ya, they doubled in size.

Comment: @surfasb: yes, c-style pointers are doubled in size, but other data types aren't necessarily. And RAM is cheap and if you're running 64-bit you probably have plenty of it.

Comment: Sigh. How do you think the memory manager references those **other** data structures. Oh, with the other 64 bit pointer. . .